# Excel - Stop Calculation on Opening to prevent circular reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large spreadsheet with a lot of built-in circular references.  I have built in VBA code to set to manual and iterative calculation on opening and also code to force a calculation on workbook open after I set to iterative calculation.  However, it appears that the workbook tries to calculate before even running this VBA code on opening, such that if the workbook is already set to automatic calculation with no iterative calculation, it runs the workbook and then crashes because of the circular references.

I know I can set my own Application settings to always have iterative calculation, but this workbook is shared with others who may not have those same Application settings.  Is there a way to halt the calculation on opening until the code has set the application to iterative calculation.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you run when the workbook opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a blank .xlsm file, in the workbook open event, put in this code

```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
       ' Add code to open the real workbook
       ' ---------
   End Sub
```

---

Since the calculations will be driven by whether or not the last opened workbook is manual or automatic, the above code will have to be put into a Caller workbook (shown above). This caller workbook, upon opening, will first disable calculations and then pull up your workbook which will be guaranteed to have manual calculation mode.

Also, in the required workbook (the one with circular references), The OnOpen event should trigger a Close of the caller workbook without saving.

That way the process is transparent to the user and s/he only opens the Caller book.

Comment: HNK, thanks for the feedback.  However, I already had that code in my workbook.  The issue seems to be that if the Application is already set to Automatic before opening the workbook, it starts to re-calculate everything before it even hits the VBA code to change the calculation setting to manual - any way to change this so that it doesn't calculate immediately upon opening the file?

Comment: btw, using Circular references is almost always a very bad idea and can lead to really hard to debug problems

Comment: HNK, I see what you are saying and that is definitely on the right track.  Does that solution though require that the end user be on the same network where my required workbook are saved?  My intention (not ideal but the way things are done) is that the files are shared by email as there are updates, so I am trying to think through how to share the caller workbook via email and also still have it be able to open the required workbook without sending two separate files.  Sorry for my ignorance but this is very helpful to me!

Comment: Not really, i mean you'll need to specify the path of the Called (your) workbook. The Caller workbook can be anywhere. The Called workbook will need to be in a 'findable' place... which can also be a shared Network drive

Comment: If this answer's helpful for you, then you can vote/mark it as answered please. tks

Comment: Thanks HNK.  That was what I was afraid of because I can't be sure that the end user will always be on the network, however, this file may be getting to the point that we'll need to require that in order for them to use it because it doesn't make sense for it to keep crashing.

Comment: aah, that's a different problem altogether, but you can keep both the files together then, so if the user can access one he can always access the other. And users can be instructed to always keep both in the same folder. Then you can use a relative path reference to open Called from Caller